# Getting the absolute (standing) position in WebVR

Tags: three.js, webvr

I am developing a WebVR application using Three.js. In it I am trying to get the standing position relative to the room.

How can I use the `VRStageParameters.sittingToStandingTransform` matrix in Three.js to transform my camera from sitting to standing space?

Comment: which three.js version and what sort of setup are you using? Maybe a few lines of code to show your VR-integration?